# How to update Preferences again after removing item to list in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have a list of CartUsers. I execute the command remove item from the list. I managed to remove each item in the list. However how does the list `Preferences` update.

My code:

1. cart.xaml

   ```
   <StackLayout Padding="15,13" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CartUsers}">
      <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <StackLayout Margin="0,2.5" x:DataType="model:CartUser">
                 <Label Text="{Binding NumberProduct}" />
                 <ImageButton x:Name="removeitem" Clicked="removeitem_Clicked" >
                    <ImageButton.Source>
                       <FontImageSource Color="red" Size="10" FontFamily="FontAwesome" Glyph="{x:Static local:FontAwesomeClass.TrashAlt}"/>
                   </ImageButton.Source>
                 </ImageButton>
              </StackLayout>
          </DataTemplate>
      </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>                                        
   </StackLayout>
   ```

2.cart.xaml.cs

```
CartUserViewModel cartUserViewModel;
private void removeitem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mycart = Preferences.Get("CartUser", "defaultcart");
        var getcart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartUser>>(mycart);

        var button = sender as ImageButton;
        var itemcart = button.BindingContext as CartUser;

        cartUserViewModel.RemoveItemCart.Execute(itemcart);

        //Preferences.Set("CartUser", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getcart));
    }
```

**Update...**

```
private void removeitem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mycart = Preferences.Get("CartUser", "defaultcart");
        var getcart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartUser>>(mycart);

        var button = sender as ImageButton;
        var itemcart = button.BindingContext as CartUser;

        cartUserViewModel.RemoveItemCart.Execute(itemcart);
        getcart.Remove(itemcart);

        int count = getcart.Count();
        
        Preferences.Set("CartUser", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getcart));
    }
```

Comment: This is really not a great use of Preferences.  Regardless, it seems like you should save the serialized data from `cartUserViewModel` that you just updated

Comment: Yes, I will try it in many ways

Answer (score 0):

1. You just deleted a CartUser inside the ViewModel, and the Preferences have not changed.
2. According to your code, getcart is the List obtained using Preferences. You need to use `getcart.Remove(itemcart);` to delete an item. Then use your commented code to store it.

Comment: Yes, I'll try it, I'll respond right here

Comment: Wish you success

Comment: I tried like the part I updated above, but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Your current code just sets Preference, and the page is not refreshed.

Comment: Try to add getcart.Remove(itemcart);  to your original code;

Comment: Can you explain clearly by answer? I tried adding getcart.Remove(itemcart); like the above update

Comment: Yeah, so the question now is that the page is not refreshed? Please confirm whether the value of Preferences is modified. If the modification is successful, it means that your ViewModel is not dynamically refreshed.

Comment: "Please confirm whether the value of Preferences is modified"---> I check the data in Preferences still unchanged? That means it hasn't been deleted yet

Comment: So when you execute getcart.Remove(itemcart);, the value of getcart does not decrease by one, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236876/discussion-between-wen-xu-li-msft-and-chim-di-tru).